# Apache POI: como saber se uma planilha chegou ao fim?

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, xls, apache-poi, microsoft-office

estou desenvolvendo um projeto pessoal, e para esse estou usando o Java junto com o Apache POI para ler arquivos XLS, como posso saber se a planilha chegou ao seu fim? Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o iterator da sheet:

```
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {//enquanto houver linhas

            Row currentRow = iterator.next();//obtendo a linha
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();//obtendo o iterator da linha (celulas da linha)

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {//enquanto houver celulas na linha         

              //fazendo leitura de dados da celula
            }
        }
```

Para obter o número total de linhas:

```
int numeroUltimaLinha = sheet.getLastRowNum();//começa em 0, e se a planilha estiver vazia também retorna zero

int numeroTotalLinhas = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();//nao conta as linhas vazias
```

Se numeroUltimaLinha e numeroTotalLinhas forem zero, a planilha está realmente vazia, não há linhas em branco e não há linhas físicas.

[Exemplo de código para leitura e escrita de xls com Apache POI (MKyoung).](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/)